# Click on button with data- attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing an script extension for a website for Greasemonkey (or Tempermonkey). The problem occurred when I wanted to autofocus (or even autoclick) the button that contains no id, but rather data- attribute.

```
<div id="wrapper_container">
    <form id="form1" action="/?module=Action" method="post">
<table class="thinline" align="center">
    <tbody>
    <tr>    
        <td>1</td><td>Name</td><td>Surname</td><td>E-mail</td><td>Phone Number</td><td>Contact</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-small" data-info="contact" data-value="184">Go</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td>1</td><td>Name</td><td>Surname</td><td>E-mail</td><td>Phone Number</td><td>Contact</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-small" data-info="contact" data-value="185">Go</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td>1</td><td>Name</td><td>Surname</td><td>E-mail</td><td>Phone Number</td><td>Contact</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-small" data-info="contact" data-value="186">Go</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td>1</td><td>Name</td><td>Surname</td><td>E-mail</td><td>Phone Number</td><td>Contact</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-small" data-info="contact" data-value="187">Go</button></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Already tried numerous of times but got me nowhere and wondering why this is not working:

```
$("#wrapper_container button:eq(4)").focus();
```

tried to select 4th (or in future nth) button in div, but got unlucky.

I want, for example, button with data-value "186" to be either focused or clicked on pageload. Since I got more entries than displayed, I'd like to do so for every nth button that I'd choose.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The index for eq starts at 0.  So the 4th element is 3.  https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your need just focus in static way button with data-value = 186, use this:

```
$("#wrapper_container button:eq(2)").focus();
```

Look this example with more control, just pass the value of you want:

```js
$('#wrapper_container button').each(function() {
  var dataValue = $(this).data("value");
  if (dataValue == 186) {
    $(this).focus();
  }
});
```

```css
button:focus {
  background: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div id="wrapper_container">
  <form id="form1" action="/?module=Action" method="post">
    <table class="thinline" align="center">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Surname</td>
          <td>E-mail</td>
          <td>Phone Number</td>
          <td>Contact</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-small" data-info="contact" data-value="184">
               Go
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Surname</td>
          <td>E-mail</td>
          <td>Phone Number</td>
          <td>Contact</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-small" data-info="contact" data-value="185">
               Go
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Surname</td>
          <td>E-mail</td>
          <td>Phone Number</td>
          <td>Contact</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-small" data-info="contact" data-value="186">
               Go
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Surname</td>
          <td>E-mail</td>
          <td>Phone Number</td>
          <td>Contact</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-small" data-info="contact" data-value="187">
               Go
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the 4th one, you need `eq(3)` as it is a zero-indexed array.

Here are some examples that should get you on your way:

```js
$(function(){
    
    // extra bit of code to 'prove' each button is beaing clicked
    $('#wrapper_container button').on('click', function(e) {
        console.info('Button clicked, I am button with data value: ' + $(this).attr('data-value'));
    });
    
    // You know the IDs of the buttons, you could do:
    let IDs = [186, 187];
    IDs.forEach(ID => {
        console.info('Clicking button with data-value = ' + ID);
        $('[data-value=' + ID + ']').click();
    });


    // You just need a single ID:
    let ID = 187;
    console.info('Clicking single button with data-value = ' + ID);
    $('[data-value=' + ID + ']').click();
    
    
    // Select nth button in your container,
    // as you are trying the 4th button, we use 3, because it is a zero-indexed array, starting at 0 of course:
    let btn = $('#wrapper_container').find('button:eq(3)');
    console.info('Clicking 4th button in #wrapper_container');
    btn.click();
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper_container">
    <form id="form1" action="/?module=Action" method="post" onsubmit="return false">
<table class="thinline" align="center">
    <tbody>
    <tr>    
        <td>1</td><td>Name</td><td>Surname</td><td>E-mail</td><td>Phone Number</td><td>Contact</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-small" data-info="contact" data-value="184">Go</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td>1</td><td>Name</td><td>Surname</td><td>E-mail</td><td>Phone Number</td><td>Contact</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-small" data-info="contact" data-value="185">Go</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td>1</td><td>Name</td><td>Surname</td><td>E-mail</td><td>Phone Number</td><td>Contact</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-small" data-info="contact" data-value="186">Go</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td>1</td><td>Name</td><td>Surname</td><td>E-mail</td><td>Phone Number</td><td>Contact</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-small" data-info="contact" data-value="187">Go</button></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
    </form>
</div>
```